# Validate single field of ModelForm in Django

Tags: python, django, validation

I am having trouble validating a single field in Django. What I have is the following:

```
class MoForm(ModelForm):
  def check_for_zero_cost(self):
    cost = self.cleaned_data['total_cost']
    if cost <= 0:
      raise forms.ValidationError("You value is less than zero")
    return cost
```

I get an exception when I attempt to validate. This comes out as

```
global name 'forms' is not defined
```

I tried `ValidationError("You value is less than zero")` without the point to `forms`, but this raise an exception and what I want is just an error to be added to the form error list. The think the reason I am getting this errors is because I dont have `forms.ModelForm` as the first argument in my class. If I do this then I get the following error:

```
name 'forms' is not defined
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to import it.

    `from django import forms`

Comment: How are you calling that method? Usually validation takes place in `clean()` or `clean_<fieldname>()` methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't write your own method to validate individual form field. You should use `clean_<fieldname>()` method(in this case it's `clean_total_cost`) for the form, here's the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute).

```
from django import forms

class QuoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_total_cost(self):
        total_cost = self.cleaned_data['total_cost']
        if total_cost <= 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Your value is less than zero")

        return total_cost
```